# Is there a way to do a ng-hide on a html div?

Tags: html, angularjs, ng-hide, ng-init

I am trying to hide my div that has id="crossfade" where there is an ng-click event.

1) Is this possible?
2) What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myContent">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ShopME Tops</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-
 awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js
"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ContentController">

<header>
<div class="header-inner2">
    <nav>
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a ng-click="getData('SWIMWEAR')">SWIMWEAR</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('TOPS')">TOPS</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('BOTTOMS')">BOTTOMS</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('DRESSES')">DRESSES</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('SHOES')">SHOES</a></li>
            <li><a ng-click="getData('ACCESSORIES')">ACCESSORIES</a 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>

<!-- crossfade images-->
<div id= "crossfade" ng-hide="getData('TOPS')">
    <img src="images/cover1.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover2.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover3.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover4.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover5.png" alt="#">
</div>

<!-- Container for grid layout -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" ng-repeat="x in filtered | limitTo:4">
            <img class="img-responsive1" ng-src="{{x.source}}" alt="#">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So basically, anytime something in the nav bar is clicked I want to hide the crossfade div.

Here is the line of code that Im working with :

```
<div id= "crossfade" ng-hide="getData('TOPS')">
```

So in particular, when TOPS is clicked hide the div crossfade.

Instead of this happening when I load the page I get my crossfade and my TOPS data and I cant click on anything else.

Ive also experimented with ng-if and ng-init. Ng-init almost worked but my crossfade isnt implemented in angular.js it is mainly css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible. `ng-hide` expects a boolean value, either true or false. Is `getData('Tops')` returning a boolean in your controller? I would recommend using a $scope variable rather than a function to control the behavior of `ng-hide`. So in your `getData()` function, you could assign something like: `$scope.hideCrossfade = true;`.

Then in your view, just use `<div id= "crossfade" ng-hide="hideCrossfade">`. You can always change `$scope.hideCrossfade = false;` in your controller to make the div visible again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id= "crossfade" ng-hide="hideCrossfade">
    <img src="images/cover1.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover2.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover3.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover4.png" alt="#">
    <img src="images/cover5.png" alt="#">
</div>
```

and in the controller set

```
$scope.hideCrossfade = true;
```

probably inside the function getData.

I would recommend not using ids in angular.
Also, ng-show, ng-hide, ng-if = "someFunction()" is also generally discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to figure out exactly what is wrong without seeing the `getData` function but from what I can see, heres some suggestions

Firstly, never bind to a function, its hard to debug and its costly performance wise.

Here is a solution that will work.  I'd suggest either hard coding properties for each item or use an array. I've used a single property here for simplicity.

**HTML**

```
<header>
<div class="header-inner2">
    <nav>
        <ul class="center">
            <li><a ng-click="showSwimwear()">SWIMWEAR</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>

<div id= "crossfade" ng-hide="swimwearVisible">
    <img src="images/cover1.png" alt="#">
    ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
swimwearVisible = false;

showSwimwear(){
    this.swimwearVisible = !this.swimwearVisible;
}
```

All being well the div will show and hide when you click the link.  It'll also show the current state to help you debug.

Answer (score -2):

If they are in the same controller you can just set a scope variable to ng-hide. something like:

```
$scope.hideCrossfade = false;

function getData(mType) {
    $scope.hideCrossfade = true;
}
```

and in your html

```
<div id="crossfade" ng-hide="hideCrossfade">
```

If your header controller and content controller are split up, you will want to use a $broadcast

in your headerController:

```
$scope.getData = function(mType) {
    $scope.$broadcast('hideCrossfade', true);
};
```

and in your content controller

```
var deregisterFn = $scope.$on('hideCrossfade', function($event, hide) {
    $scope.hideCrossfade = hide;
};
```

Comment: Using broadcast in this manner is overkill and not a neat solution.

Comment: if they are in separate controllers you should definitely use a broadcast

Comment: No, you should almost never use broadcast. Its messy and expensive performance wise.  The best way for inter-controller communication is to use services OR, even better, adopt the component model and use one way bindings and function callbacks

Comment: then propose a solution with your way?

Comment: I have, but as everything is in one controller components or broadcast shouldn't be used. If you ever build an app with many components on screen you'll find using broadcasts liberally will cause the app to slow down

Comment: obviously if you have a ton of broadcasts and watchers it will slow it down....but for this case we talking a single one so it works very well. also if you would read my answer it clearly says that if they the header controller and content controller are split up THEN use a broadcast

Comment: Maybe you should look up the latest Angular guidelines on components as it's worth a read https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component